# Adding Dynamic Text as Text Element in ArcMap 10.2

Tags: dynamic, text, element, arcmap

I am creating an Add-in button in ArcMap 10.2 that adds a floating concatenated dynamic text box to the map layout. I'm having a hard time with my script and am hoping someone will have an answer.

Here is my code:

```
def onClick(self):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", " ")[0]:
        elmWidth = 4.0
        x = 100
        elm.text = 'User: <dyn type="user"/> Date: <dyn type="date" format="short"/> <Document Path: dyn type="document" property="path"/>'
        elm.fontSize = x
        while elm.elementWidth > float(elmWidth):
            elm.fontSize = x
            x = x-1
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    del mxd
```

I'm getting errors of UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mxd' referenced before assignment and IndexError: list index out of range 
I'm stuck and need help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't add a new text element to an mxd layout, you can only modify or copy existing ones.
Second, write either:

```
for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", " "):
   ...
```

or

```
elm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", " ")[0]
```

This supposes there is a text element named " " in your mxd.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just add the map document dynamic text through the tools in ArcMap.